# Return the object as it(without sorting) is by comparing object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to sort the object I have based on two of its properties.

I have an object as follows,

```
    0:Object
        $id:"1"
        MetricValue:8
        GeoValue:"EAST"
        DimensionValue:High
        DocCount:28

    1:Object
        $id:"2"
        MetricValue:20
        GeoValue:"EAST"
        DimensionValue:Medium
        DocCount:28
    2:Object
        $id:"3"
        MetricValue:10
        GeoValue:"West"
        DimensionValue:High
        DocCount:30
    3:Object
        $id:"4"
        MetricValue:20
        GeoValue:"West"
        DimensionValue:Medium
        DocCount:30
```

I want to sort the object based on the doc count and the geovalue i.e. I want the sorted object to return the objects with the higher doccount value first and lower values subsequently.

i.e. as show below

```
        0:Object
            $id:"1"
            MetricValue:10
            GeoValue:"WEST"
            DimensionValue:High
            DocCount:30

        1:Object
            $id:"2"
            MetricValue:20
            GeoValue:"WEST"
            DimensionValue:Medium
            DocCount:30
        2:Object
            $id:"3"
            MetricValue:8
            GeoValue:"EAST"
            DimensionValue:High
            DocCount:28
        3:Object
            $id:"4"
            MetricValue:20
            GeoValue:"EAST"
            DimensionValue:Medium
            DocCount:28
```

The below method is what I am trying with, but with no success
here `result` is the object which has the object that I mentioned above.

```
var Final= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
 var top10 = Final.sort(function (a, b) { return a.DocCount < b.DocCount ? 1 : -1; })
        .slice(0, 10);
```

Can some one guide me through the right path?

Comment: You don't seem to have JSON at all, and stringifying an object just to parse it back makes no sense. Also, what exactly isn't working? Are there any errors etc ?

Comment: When you `console.log` your objects for showing them in the question, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`. Then we can see them more like valid JavaScript objects than these pseudo objects you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of objects for the use you make of the .sort() method:

```js
var data = [{
  $id:"1",
  MetricValue:8,
  GeoValue:"EAST",
  DimensionValue:"High",
  DocCount:28
},{
  $id:"2",
  MetricValue:20,
  GeoValue:"EAST",
  DimensionValue:"Medium",
  DocCount:28
},{
  $id:"3",
  MetricValue:10,
  GeoValue:"West",
  DimensionValue:"High",
  DocCount:30
},{
  $id:"4",
  MetricValue:20,
  GeoValue:"West",
  DimensionValue:"Medium",
  DocCount:30
}]
console.log("Original: ", data);

data.sort(function(a,b) {
  return (a.DocCount !== b.DocCount) 
    ? (a.DocCount < b.DocCount) 
    : a.GeoValue > b.GeoValue;
})
console.log("Sorted: ", data);
```